# Como obter total de vendas por meses com mysql

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela de vendas que registra a data e hora da venda.

**O formato de saída é este:**

"2018-09-02 15:00:08"

Queria obter o total de vendas por mês mas estou com dificuldade de montar a query. Como consigo filtrar somente o mês a partir de um dado mais complexo como o que tenho?

**O resultado deveria ser semelhante a isto**:

 janeiro - 10 vendas

 fevereiro - 5 vendas

Estrutura da tabela:

```
id | data_hora | total_pagamento
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta você agrupar pelo ano e pelo mês:

```
SELECT CONCAT(LPAD(MONTH(data_hora), 2, '0'), '/', YEAR(data_hora)) mes, COUNT(id) qtde
FROM nome_da_sua_tabela
GROUP BY YEAR(data_hora), MONTH(data_hora)
```

**Funções**

- [`YEAR()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) - Retorna o ano de uma data.
- [`MONTH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) - Retorna o mês de uma data.
- [`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) - Concatena os valores passados separados por `,`.
- [`LPAD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) - Completa uma `string` até que ela obtenha uma quantidade específica de caracteres.
- [`COUNT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html) - Conta as linhas retornadas.

**GROUP BY**

É responsável por agrupar a consulta, neste caso pelo ano e pelo mês. Veja mais sobre ele [aqui](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html).